# How do I merge multiple contingency tables into one using R?

Tags: r

I have multiple columns that I need to merge and return a contingency table counting each number.

Example of an ordinal data set:

```
df <- data.frame(ab = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 ba = c(1,3,3,3,5)) 
>ab ba
  1  1
  2  3
  3  3
  4  3
  5  5
```

I would like to be able to return a contingency table showing like this:

```
>1  2  3  4  5 
 2  1  4  1  2
```

Ive attempted examples featured on here for similar issues, but I get the sums returned instead of a count:

```
library(plyr)

colSums(rbind.fill(data.frame(t(unclass(df$ab))), data.frame(t(unclass(df$ba)))),`
        na.rm = T)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: is your ba column in df correct? The output column of ba is not the same as in df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We `unlist` the `data.frame` into a `vector` and apply `table` in `base R`

```
table(unlist(df))
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 2 1 4 1 2
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, by reshaping the data into 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and get the `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    count(value)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ab = 1:5, ba = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L)),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```